# Vaadin missing SpringSecurityContext in StreamResource callback method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I got a simple StreamResource example where SpringSecurityContext mysteriously disappears when clicking on the download anchor. Basically when download anchor is clicked `createInputStream` method is called for download file creation but when this method is executed SecurityContext is null. Below a simplified example that reproduces the issue.

```
public class HomeView extends VerticalLayout {

public HomeView() {
    Anchor anchor = new Anchor();
    anchor.add("DOWNLOAD");
    anchor.setHref(new StreamResource("file", () -> createInputStream()));
    add(anchor);
    // SecurityContext returns correct value and is not null.
    System.err.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
    System.err.println("Thread name in constructor : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

private InputStream createInputStream() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        outputStream.write("text".getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // SecurityContextHolder.getContext() returns null here. Why?
    System.err.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
    System.err.println("Thread name in createInputStream() : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}}
```

When this code is executed I get following messages.

```
org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@db426455: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@db426455: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@983d0d8b...Rest omitted

Thread name in constructor : http-nio-8080-exec-4

org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication

Thread name in createInputStream() : http-nio-8080-exec-9
```

But I found out that one way to fix the issue is to set the SecurityContext manually in the `createInputStream` method. Below an example.

```
public class HomeView extends VerticalLayout {

SecurityContext context;

public HomeView() {
    Anchor anchor = new Anchor();
    anchor.add("DOWNLOAD");
    anchor.setHref(new StreamResource("file", () -> createInputStream()));
    add(anchor);
    // Save Context to a variable
    context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    System.err.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
}

private InputStream createInputStream() {
    // Set SecurityContext before accessing it.
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        outputStream.write("text".getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // SecurityContextHolder.getContext() no longer returns null.
    System.err.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
}}
```

In the end I got this question. **Why is Spring SecurityContext lost in the first example is there a better way to fix this or am I stuck with the second example?**

As a side note I realised that Vaadin's Upload component is having the same issue. SecurityContext is lost in `addSucceededListener` callback method.

I'm using Vaadin 13.0.1 and Spring Boot 2.1.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was with Spring Security's WebSecurity configuration below an example which is a direct copy from Vaadin's Bakery app example.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
       .antMatchers(
               // Vaadin Flow static resources
               "/VAADIN/**", // This was the problematic spot

               //Rest of configuration omitted for simplicity
}
```

The issue was that dynamically created files via StreamResource or Upload Component are mapped to a url that has a following prefix `/VAADIN/dynamic/resource/**`. In the above configuration we tell Spring Security with `/VAADIN/**` to **ignore** all requests starting with `/VAADIN/`. This leads Spring Security to ignore all HttpServletRequest that point to dynamically created resource since Vaadin maps them with `/VAADIN/dynamic/resource/**` url prefix. When Spring Security ignores a HttpServletRequest it's SpringSecurityContext will be empty. See [WebSecurity.ignoring()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html#ignoring--) documentation.

The issue can be fixed by renaming `/VAADIN/**` to `/VAADIN/static/**`. This will prevent Spring Security from ignoring requests to dynamic resources and thus SpringSecurityContext will be available in StreamResource and Upload callback methods. Below a working example.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
       .antMatchers(
               // Vaadin Flow static resources
               "/VAADIN/static/**",

               //Rest of configuration omitted for simplicity
}
```

Comment: Corresponding issue on [github](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/5323).

Comment: I had to add "/VAADIN/build/**" to ignoring part, otherwise Login page was blank.